# htaccess mod_rewrite subdomain to subdomain

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using mod_rewrite to redirect from subdomain to maindomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698230/using-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-from-subdomain-to-maindomain)

I have an existing subdomain set up on cpanel, which points to a folder in the web root. So, go.example.com points to a php application located at www.example.com/go. Cpanel handles all of this.

At www.example.com/go, I have a .htaccess file as follows, which basically removes the index.php front controller from the url:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This all works fine.

However, I now have a requirement to add another subdomain (api.example.com), that points to another folder located at www.example.com/go/api:

Firstly, should api.example.com point to www.example.com/go/api or to go.example.com/api ?
Secondly, how would I achieve this in the htaccess file?

Comment: Either http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p - I bet for both variants this has been asked before. Also you need to say what should. I find it hard to decide it for you because it depends on your needs, not mine.

Comment: I'd love to see the exact duplicate of this